# same request, result different with oraclesqldeveloper or command line

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

why it is not the same result with **command line**  type directly on the oracle server apres logging

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus
*vis/passwd@10.252.41.123:1521/AA*

SQL> select count(*) from dispo where period = to_date('2017-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ;
result : 0
```

and when i use the software **Oracle sql developper** with a connection with the same *vis/passwdv@10.252.41.123:1521/AA*?

```
select count(*) from dispo where period = to_date('2017-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
result : 20000
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlfDe.png)

Comment: Is all the data committed? If so, what is the data type of the period column?

Comment: Type `commit` in `Oracle sql developper` and the use `SQL> select count(*) from dispo where period = to_date('2017-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ;`

Comment: yes all data commited. Type TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL*Plus and SQL Developer sessions are in, or think they are in, different time zones.

The static date you're using for the filter is being implicitly converted to the local time zone. When that happens in your SQL*Plus session/time zone it still matches the timestamps you have stored. When you do it in the SQL Developer session/time zone it doesn't match.

You can demonstrate this in a single session by altering the session settings, with a single dummy row created in a UTC session:

```
create table dispo (id number, period timestamp(6) with local time zone);
alter session set time_zone = 'UTC';
insert into dispo (id, period) values (1, timestamp '2017-10-01 00:00:00');
```

then querying in the same time zone sees that data:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'UTC';
select cast(date '2017-01-01' as timestamp with local time zone) as local_time from dual;

LOCAL_TIME         
-------------------
2017-01-01 00:00:00

select * from dispo where period = date '2017-10-01';

        ID PERIOD             
---------- -------------------
         1 2017-10-01 00:00:00
```

but querying in a different time zone does not:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/London';
select cast(date '2017-01-01' as timestamp with local time zone) as local_time from dual;

LOCAL_TIME         
-------------------
2017-01-01 00:00:00

select * from dispo where period = date '2017-10-01';

no rows selected
```

You can avoid this by specifying which time zone the fixed value is in:

```
alter session set time_zone = 'UTC';
select * from dispo where period = timestamp '2017-10-01 00:00:00 UTC';

        ID PERIOD             
---------- -------------------
         1 2017-10-01 00:00:00

alter session set time_zone = 'Europe/London';
select * from dispo where period = timestamp '2017-10-01 00:00:00 UTC';

        ID PERIOD             
---------- -------------------
         1 2017-10-01 00:00:00
```

Obviously use whichever time zone the data was actually created in...

Comment: Thanks you very much, very interesting